# Table view from core data not showing all results. Only first

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to save a few simple entries into a core data entity (with about 6 attributes) and have them populate a table view with the list of one of the attributes (e.g. table view with a list of all student names entered).

So far I am able to save multiple entries, confirmed that they are in core data (I have a button setup that reads core data and a pop-up alert shows all the entries) but the table view always shows only the first entry in core data.

```
@implementation ViewController

AppDelegate *appDelegate;
NSArray *tableData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    appDelegate =(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Students"];
    NSError *requestError = nil;
    tableData = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&requestError];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    NSManagedObject *entityObject = (NSManagedObject *)[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [entityObject valueForKey:@"Surname"];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: have you checked tabledata count.

Comment: Thanks - I realised that if I add multiple entries before I load the table view it will show all the entries.

How do I get the tableview to update after I enter more entries into core data and the table view is already loaded/showing entries?

Comment: After each addition reload tableview or section of table view depends on requirement.Make sure it will be updated on main thread.

Comment: you probably don't need to update on **every** row loaded, depending on how many you have.  Unless the user is scrolling down while you are loading, you won't see any benefit from reloading after the first page is displayed.  What you **do** need is to make sure you reload after the last entry has been load.  and as @Rohit says, make sure you do it on the main thread!

Comment: I have the following code:

    `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *studentList;`

I then did:

`[self.studentList reloadData];`

In the following place

`- (void)viewDidLoad {

}`

But this does not reload the table view when I change back and forth between tabs (I have a tab bar controller scene). One particular scene has a table view placed onto it.

Comment: Basically in the tab bar controller one particular scene has a table view placed onto it and when I switch back and forth this tab and the next the table data remains the same (in the first tab I can add entries, in the second is the table view).